# Replacing an SVG with javascript sometimes fails to finish

Tags: javascript, image, svg

I have some code that replaces one small SVG with another. Both are scaled to the same size. Under some circumstances, yet to be determined, the replacement image... doesn't finish loading? (I'm not sure what happens: The old image is a green "+" and the replacement is a red "X". Sometimes I get the red "X", sometimes a tiny little pixel or two of red instead in the upper left corner.) Both images are on the same server as the script and HTML:

HTML

```
<td id="internal_add_more.1"><img
    src="/images/icons/add_green.svg"
    alt="[+]"
    title="Add"
    style="height:1em; width:1em;" /></td>
```

Javascript:

```
var oldAdd = document.getElementById(prefix+"add_more."+oldRow);  // a cell (td)
var undo = oldAdd.childNodes[0];                                  // img in cell
undo.src = "/images/icons/delete_red.svg";
undo.alt = "[X]";
undo.title = "Remove";
```